# Python3.4 convert int16_t string to signed float

Tags: python, type-conversion, python-3.4

I apologise if this question has already been answered here. My searches have turned up similar questions but I have been unsuccessful in applying them to my situation.

I receive data via serial communication as two 16bit hexadecimal bytes. Now represented by two python integers. `[48822, 15938]`

These bytes represent a signed floating point variable. i.e. `[48822, 15938]`-->`[0xbeb6, 0x3e42]`-->`[0x3e42beb6]`-->`[0.190181]`

How would I complete this conversion in python3.4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import struct
>>> f = struct.unpack('f',struct.pack('HH', 48822,15938))[0]
>>> f
0.19018062949180603
>>>
```

You can use `*lst` to convert your list to parameters for `struct.pack`.

Comment: How is it working? Can you describe what is happening here? I am curious.

Comment: You should check the documentation for `struct`.  If you're working with byte streams, it is invaluable.  It's basically doing C casting.  The `pack` says "take the first two parameters as signed half-words".  It converts them to a 4-byte "bytes" string.  Unpack then takes a 4-byte "bytes" string and casts it to a single-precision floating point value.  It produces a list (since there can be multiple converters), so we have to take the first element.

Answer (score -1):

If you're getting a significant amount of data this way, you may want to consider using numpy. You can pack a buffer of dtype `np.uint16` and view the contents directly as `np.float32` without copying any data:

```
n = 1
buffer = np.zeros(2 * n, dtype=np.uint16)
floats = buffer.view(np.float32)
buffer[:2] = [48822, 15938]
print(floats)
```